# Am scripting using C# in Unity but cant run code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting started with scripting in Unity and after running the attached codes. i get the error in the unity console. Any assistance for me.

Error in unity image.

[image]

This the the code i run in the VS for the unity.

enter code here

```
**using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start method is Called");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Update is calling");
    }
}**
```

Comment: Do you have any other Script in your Project?

Comment: No Please. just this one. Am new to the unity platform trying to start the scripting process.

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 Classes  named CubeScript in your project. its the reason of error

Look at other script if one contains the same name of class

to avoid duplicate classes, you could add namespace too:

```
namespace NameOfSceneForExample
{
    public class CubeScript : MonoBehaviour
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: kk...So how should the script be written for it to work?

Comment: the best solution is to add namespace see my modified answer